# Python tkinter get function

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have two python files - main.py and dictionary.py . I am creating an 8 in 1 app. When I run dictionary.py, I can get the meaning of the desired word but while running main.py, the value of the variables gets lost.

While running main.py, the value of text_v gets reset. But while running only dictionary.py, the value of text_v remains the same. I don't know why it is happening. Please help

main.py

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import dictionary as dc


win = tk.Tk()
win.geometry("1280x720+100-100")


calc_icon = Image.open("calculator_icon.png")
calc_icon = ImageTk.PhotoImage(calc_icon)
print(type(calc_icon))
calc_button = tk.Button(win, image=calc_icon, borderwidth=0)
calc_button.place(x=160, y=180, anchor='center')

timetable_icon = Image.open("timetable_icon.png")
timetable_icon = ImageTk.PhotoImage(timetable_icon)
timetable_button = tk.Button(win, image=timetable_icon, borderwidth=0)
timetable_button.place(x=480, y=180, anchor='center')

texteditor_icon = Image.open("texteditor_icon.png")
texteditor_icon = ImageTk.PhotoImage(texteditor_icon)
texteditor_button = tk.Button(win, image=texteditor_icon, borderwidth=0)
texteditor_button.place(x=800, y=180, anchor='center')

dictionary_icon = Image.open("dictionary.png")
dictionary_icon = ImageTk.PhotoImage(dictionary_icon)
dictionary_button = tk.Button(win, image=dictionary_icon, borderwidth=0, command=dc.dic)
dictionary_button.place(x=1120, y=180, anchor='center')

budget_icon = Image.open("budgetmanager.png")
budget_icon = ImageTk.PhotoImage(budget_icon)
budget_button = tk.Button(win, image=budget_icon, borderwidth=0)
budget_button.place(x=160, y=450, anchor='center')

todo_icon = Image.open("todo.png")
todo_icon = ImageTk.PhotoImage(todo_icon)
todo_button = tk.Button(win, image=todo_icon, borderwidth=0)
todo_button.place(x=480, y=450, anchor='center')

bookmark_icon = Image.open("bookmark.png")
bookmark_icon = ImageTk.PhotoImage(bookmark_icon)
bookmark_button = tk.Button(win, image=bookmark_icon, borderwidth=0)
bookmark_button.place(x=800, y=450, anchor='center')

news_icon = Image.open("news.png")
news_icon = ImageTk.PhotoImage(news_icon)
news_button = tk.Button(win, image=news_icon, borderwidth=0)
news_button.place(x=1120, y=450, anchor='center')

win.mainloop()
```

dictionary.py

```
import tkinter as tk
import PyDictionary as pd

def dic():



def click():

    m_canvas = tk.Canvas(win)

    print('line 12', text_v)
    word = text_v.get()

    print(word)
    m_canvas.place(x=300, y=0)
    m_label = tk.Label(m_canvas, text='Meaning', font=('Callibri', 20))
    m_label.grid(row=0, column=0)

    translated = pd.PyDictionary.meaning(word)
    print(translated)
    meaning = tk.Label(m_canvas, text=translated, font=('Callibri', 15))
    meaning.grid(row=1, column=0)

win = tk.Tk()
win.title('Dictionary')
win.geometry('1280x720+100-100')

text_v = tk.StringVar()

print('line 31', text_v)



canvas = tk.Canvas(win)
canvas.place(x=0, y=0, anchor='nw')
head = tk.Label(canvas, text='Dictionary:', font=('Callibri, 20'))
head.grid(row=0, column=0)
lab = tk.Label(canvas, text='Enter a word', font=('Callibri', 20))
lab.grid(row=1, column=0)

inp = tk.Entry(canvas, textvariable=text_v)


inp.grid(row=2, column=0)
lab2 = tk.Label(canvas, text='')
lab2.grid(row=3, column=0)
btn = tk.Button(canvas, text='Submit', command=click)
btn.grid(row=4, column=0)





win.mainloop()
```

Comment: It is because you have multiple instances of `Tk()` when `dc.dic()` is executed.

Comment: so what can I do?

Comment: Either use `Toplevel()` instead of `Tk()` inside `dictionary.py` or change `text_v = tk.StringVar()` to `text_v = tk.StringVar(master=win)`.  Also avoid calling `mainloop()` more than once.